# The memset() function

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to C/C++, and I came across the following segment of code:

```
#define MAX_MSG 1000
char *szBuf = new char[MAX_MSG];
char *szBufRaw = new char[MAX_MSG];
memset(szBuf, ‘\0’, strlen(szBuf));
memset(szBufRaw, ‘\0’, strlen(szBufRaw));
```

I've read the tutorial about memset here:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=591

and I believe the above code is correct, but the original author of the code believes there is a bug within it, could anybody give me a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strlen(szBuf)`(and `strlen(szBufRaw)`) will return correct result only on valid strings. You should pass `MAX_MSG` instead.

Answer (score 6):

strlen() looks for the first null value in the array, which means that you won't memset the right amount of bytes in memory.

Use MAX_MSG instead to set the entire array to null.

Answer (score 3):

Both char arrays are uninitialized, the use of `strlen()` on them is undefined behavior. It will not do what you expect.

`strlen()` walks through a string, given the pointer to its first character, and return the length of the string, that is, until it finds the terminating zero. After you create these arrays with `new`, they don't contain anything meaningful. these calls may return anything, and may even crash your program.

What you want is to pass the size of the arrays:

```
memset(szBuf, ‘\0’, MAX_MSG);
memset(szBufRaw, ‘\0’, MAX_MSG);
```

Comment: Aren't they both zeroed out before `new` returns?

Comment: @cHao no, they contain whatever was in that memory. The memory is not initialized.

Comment: @cHao: `char` is one of the basic types, and doesn't have a constructor. So they are uninitialized when you instantiate them.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen()` returns the length of a string given.
The length is defined as the length between the head and the tail whose value is `\0`.

In the code above, `strlen()` will not necessarily returns `MAX_MSG`, because you haven't initialize or set some value yet.

```
memset(szBuf, ‘\0’, sizeof(szBuf))
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

strlen will not behave as you expect because it counts the number of bytes before a NUL (0 ascii code) char. What you need is to pass MAX_MSG instead of strlen. By the way, is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `memset`, the two buffers `szBuf` and `szBufRaw` are uninitialized.  However, to get the length of memory to clear, the code calls `strlen` on them.  That won't work because the buffers don't contain valid strings.  The code should be clearing `MAX_MSG` bytes in the buffers instead of using `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

> `memset(szBuf, ‘\0’, strlen(szBuf));`

Whats `strlen()` doing in there? Where are the strings?

The `strlen()` function returns the number of characters that precede the terminating null
character in a C style string.

`memset(szBuf, ‘\0’, MAX_MSG);` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized memory allocated by `new` won't behave nice with `strlen()`.

It'd be better if one wrote:

```
memset(szBuf, 0, MAX_MSG * sizeof *szBuf);
```

You could also skip `sizeof *szBuf` since it's guaranteed to be 1, but it doesn't hurt.